# How to wait for Room to update?

Tags: kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to make a function that first updates a model field in a Database, then imediatly retrives this same model. I'd like to get that model with the udpated field. I'm trying this:

```
var snack = appViewModel.getSnack(snackId)
runBlocking { appViewModel.updateSnack(snack.copy(total = value)) } 
snack = appViewModel.getSnack(snackId)
```

However, even when using `runBlocking`, snack ends up being with the old `total` value. I don't know how Room suspending functions for @Update are implemented, but it seems that even with `runBlocking` this runs assyncrhronaly, so the field doesn't get updated in time. How do I proceed?

Comment: What does your view model function look like? Room DAO suspend functions do run synchronously, but maybe you changed its behavior somewhere your DAO and view model. You definitely should not be using runBlocking. It’s not supposed to ever be used inside a coroutine and if you use it elsewhere you are probably blocking the main thread.

Comment: You were right. My viewmodel implementation calls the DAO suspend function from a viewModelScope.launch(), so it returns right away. However, I'm curious to why I shoudn't use runBlocking. How am I suposed to wait for Room to conclue it's operation then? All my getItem(id) functions are implemented with runBlocking, because I need the results,.

Comment: The whole reason to define suspend functions in your DAO is to avoid blocking the main thread. They are time consuming, which means if they run on the main thread, they block it, making the graphics stuttery and janky, and risking an ANR crash. You should do all your repository work in suspend functions and actual coroutines launched from `viewModelScope`. You get the result in the coroutine and you use the result in that same coroutine.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Using the result in the coroutine wasn't possible, because I needed the result imediatly on my UI. But thanks to your reply, I figured I'm not modeling this right. I changed my @Get on the Dao to return a Flow<>, and then I set a .collectAsState() on my UI. Now everything is working fine! Thanks.

Comment: That's an alternate way and probably more sensible when using Compose. I think Compose-related questions are still in the minority here so I recommend mentioning that in your questions. Note that is not immediately updating the UI either. The flow will suspend until the first result arrives, and that will update the state, causing a recomposition.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tenfour04 pointed out, my implementation in the ViewModel was launching a viewModelScope, so the function returned imediately, and runBlocking{} was useless. As a temporary measure, I just added **.join()** to the runBlocking call, so it waits for the Job to finish:

```
runBlocking { appViewModel.updateSnack(snack.copy(total = value)).join() }
```

As @Tenfour04 also pointed out, my design is flawed, because we shoudn't be blocking the UI. I'm now trying to implement everything with Flow<> and collectAsState().